# Nested IIF gives error

Tags: ms-access, nested, vba, iif

Am building a report in Report builder and creating a calculated field.

When I try and enter the expression

```
=iif(IsNothing(Fields!DDICU.Value),"",iif(fields!DDICU.value > Parameters!end.value,"00:00",fields!TDICU.value.tostring))
```

I get an error when the `DDICU.value` is empty but the nested `iif` statement works correctly when there is a value in `DDICU`

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The `IIF()`operator evaluates both the *TRUE* and the *FALSE* clause, before giving the result. Thus, if the *FALSE* clause is giving an error, it will still throw an error.

See the following example:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    If True Then
        Debug.Print 2
    Else
        Debug.Print 0 / 0
    End If

    Debug.Print IIf(True, 1, 0 / 0)

End Sub
```

Both `IF` and `IIF` look pretty much the same, but the VBA will throw error at the `IIF()`, because it will try to calculate `0/0`. By the `If` condition it will not throw an error, because it will not try to calculate the `0/0`.

Comment: but when the DDICU has a value - the expression evaluates correctly - only when the DDICU doesnt have a value do I get the error

Comment: @PhilStuart-Douek - see the edit, try to build it with standard if-else.

Comment: the false clause is not giving the error - it is the true clause that is giving the error

Comment: @PhilStuart-Douek - try to rewrite it with `If-ElseIf-End If` and to check once again.